# Linking of two dll files to create output txt file

Tags: visual-studio, dll, linker, fortran, output

I use this program to link two dll files together in visual studio to create a txt file in a specified directory. However, I see there is a problem in reading the two dll files using this program. So, can someone help me with that ?

```
  program main
  use kernel32
  integer(handle) lib_handle
  integer(handle) user_handle
  pointer(SAMSDLLPNT,SAMSDLL)
  user_handle = LoadLibrary("C:/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/Dll problem/
 + AHMED2020/SamsUser.dll"C)
  lib_handle = LoadLibrary("C:/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/Dll problem/
 + AHMED2020/SamsIF.dll"C)
  if (lib_handle == 0) stop "Library not loaded"
  SAMSDLLPNT = GetProcAddress(lib_handle, "SAMSDLL"C)
  if (SAMSDLLPNT == 0) stop "SAMSDLL subroutine not found"
  call SAMSDLL
  end program
```

Comment: What kind of problem? Also, if the DLLs are hard-coded in the program, why not link the DLLs with the executable?

Comment: Not sure if LoadLibrary understands /.  Try changing / to \.  Also, if they are C libraries, are they stdcall or cdecl functions/subroutines.

Comment: How can I link the DLLs with the executable ?

Comment: They are functions subroutines